# Does Informix support several threads creating the same-named temporary table?

Tags: eclipselink, informix

I am in the process of fixing EclipseLink's `InformixPlatform` database support class to work with our Informix 11.70 installation.

One of the contracts that needs work is expressed by the following code.  The documentation explains what is needed:

```
/**
 * INTERNAL:
 * Indicates whether the platform supports local temporary tables.
 * "Local" means that several threads may create
 * temporary tables with the same name.
   [snip]
 */
 public boolean supportsLocalTempTables() {
     return true; // is this correct?
 }

/**
 * INTERNAL:
 * Indicates whether the platform supports global temporary tables.
 * "Global" means that an attempt to create temporary table with the same
 * name for the second time results in exception.
   [snip]
 * Note that this method is ignored in case supportsLocalTempTables() returns true.
 */
 public boolean supportsGlobalTempTables() {
     return false; // is this correct?
 }
```

My sense is that I should return `true` from my implementation of `supportsLocalTempTables()`, because I think that Informix does indeed support the ability to create, for example, a temporary table named `FRED` from session 1, and a temporary table *also* named `FRED` from session 2.  Is my assumption correct?

I consulted [the Informix 11.70 InfoCenter topic](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.admin.doc%2Fids_admin_0520.htm) but did not see anything specific there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Temporary tables in Informix are local to the session and visible only by the session.
In addition, when the session closes, all its temporary tables are dropped.
So, in different sessions you can create temporary tables with the same name.
There is no way to share access to temporary tables between sessions.

Comment: Thanks, Fernando; I am hoping to get the official `InformixPlatform.java` for EclipseLink patched with these necessary changes; for now I'm just overriding it.  I wanted to make sure I had the right information.